# using an event to command trigger inside a style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to use the Mvvm Light toolkit to bind an event to a command from within a style.

I currently have the style:

```
<Style 
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
xmlns:controls='clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls'
xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' 
xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'
xmlns:mc='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006'
xmlns:ig='http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml'
xmlns:i='http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity'
xmlns:Command='clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4'
TargetType='ig:EventSpan'>
      <Setter Property='Template'>
           <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType='ig:EventSpan'>
                      <Grid Margin='0,2,0,2'>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                  <i:EventTrigger EventName='MouseEnter'>
                                        <Command:EventToCommand Command='{Binding EventSpan_MouseEnter1}' CommandParameter='{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ig:EventSpan}}}'/>
                                  </i:EventTrigger>
                                  <i:EventTrigger EventName='MouseLeave'>
                                        <Command:EventToCommand Command='{Binding EventSpan_MouseLeave1}' CommandParameter='{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ig:EventSpan}}}'/>
                                  </i:EventTrigger>
                             </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                       <Rectangle RadiusX='0' RadiusY='0' Fill='{TemplateBinding Fill}' Stroke='{TemplateBinding Stroke}' StrokeThickness='0' Height='0' Margin='0, 0, 0, 0' VerticalAlignment='Top' />
                       </Grid>
                 </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
</Style>
```

and an example of the code behind is:

```
private RelayCommand<string> _eventSpan_MouseEnter;
public RelayCommand<string> EventSpan_MouseEnter1
{
    get
    {
        return _eventSpan_MouseEnter
            ?? (_eventSpan_MouseEnter = new RelayCommand<string>(
                                  sender =>
                                  {
                                      MouseOverLayer = sender;
                                  }));
    }
}
```

But this command never fires and I cannot work out why?

PS. The reason that the libraries are referenced in the styles is because this style is loaded dynamically from code behind. It is legacy code that I am currently trying to convert to mvvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So There were two problems with the way I had bound before. Firstly the main reason was that the style had no datacontext. And apparently didnt inherit the datacontext from the template implementing the style. and also that the command parameter was incorrect.

```
CommandParameter='{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ig:EventSpan}}}'
```

was binding to a relaycommand expecting a string parameter and so crashed. Therefore the correct commandparameter was

```
CommandParameter='{Binding Path=EventEntry.Series.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ig:EventSpan}}}'
```